# Is there a shutter speed control in Sony QX10/100 API?

Tags: camera, sony

I've download the latest SDK (CameraRemoteAPIbeta_SDK_1.40). The document didn't mention there's a shutter speed control in the API, but QX100 firmware 2.0 provides this feature in "PlayMemories Mobile" app. So is there a shutter control API in SDK 1.40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was added in API 1.50.

Though only qx100 has it, qx10 does not currently support it (and may never).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for inquiry.
Shutter speed control for QX100 is available using firmware 3.00 or later.

Best Regards,
Prem, Member of Developer World team at Sony